# Redefine macro to append item(s) to it

Tags: c, gcc, macros, concatenation

I am trying to redefine a macro to append another macro to it.

When APPEND_ITEM is defined, I got the following error at compile time:
**warning: "LIST" redefined

error: 'LIST' undeclared here (not a function)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "item.h"

#define LIST 1, 2, 3
#define ITEM 4

#ifdef APPEND_ITEM
#define LIST LIST, ITEM
#endif

uint8_t arr[] = {LIST};

int main()
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:
1 2 3 4

I am using GCC.

Comment: Because the contents of a `#define` are not expanded immediately. They're expanded when you use the macro later. So this isn't possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? What is your use case?

Comment: I want to be able to change the size of arr[] variable at compile time, and to initialize it. ITEM is kind of optional. I will update the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to change the size of arr[] variable at compile time

In this case you don't need to redefine the list (which on the other hand is not possible as others have explained since `LIST` expands to its literal values when used), but you can embed the `ITEM` directly into the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define LIST 1, 2, 3
#define ITEM 4

#define APPEND_ITEM

uint8_t arr[] = {
    LIST
#ifdef APPEND_ITEM
    , ITEM
#endif
};

int main()
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compiler switches in the middle of application code is painful though. In this case I would probably hide the whole initializer list behind a macro so you've got `uuint8_t arr[] = { ARR_INIT };` and then have the `ARR_INIT` expand to either `LIST` or `LIST, ITEM` depending on APPEND_ITEM.

Comment: @Lundin Sounds good. It seems that OP is open to suggestions. Feel free to edit and add your alternative (or to post your own answer of course)

Answer (score 1):

Every time the pre-compiler meets LIST in your code, it substitutes it with the contents of #define, i.e. with LIST, ITEM.

It cannot recursively get into it and look, what LIST and ITEM were previously; it's not the task. It is treated just like a piece of c-code, where the expression "LIST, ITEM" doesn't have sense.

So that just doesn't work.

But you can use functions inside of a #define.

Answer (score 1):

For readability and easy maintenance, consider using this version (no `#ifdef` clutter in the middle of functions):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
    
#define LIST_INIT 1, 2, 3
#define ITEM 4

#ifdef ITEM
  #define LIST LIST_INIT, ITEM
#else
  #define LIST LIST_INIT
#endif

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[] = { LIST };

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\r\n");
    return 0;
}
```